# How to change the theme of a Highstock graph with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So I import a few different themes like this:

```
<script src="/js/themes/skies.js"></script>
<script src="/js/themes/sand-signika.js"></script>
<script src="/js/themes/grid.js"></script>
<script src="/js/themes/grid-light.js"></script>
<script src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
<script src="/js/themes/dark-unica.js"></script>
<script src="/js/themes/dark-green.js"></script>
<script src="/js/themes/dark-blue.js"></script>
```

And I activate them like this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.skies);
```

Putting this above the graph works just fine, but when I try to use buttons so that I can change them on my website, nothing happens. What I've tried is this:

```
$('#skies').click(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.skies);
});
```

I know that the button works, as I've tested it with window.alert(), but why doesn't the theme get updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Highcharts.setOptions` doesn't update charts, only.. change default options for a new charts. So in your case, you need to recreate chart.

Comment: Is there any way to change theme ? how to re-create the chart

Comment: Changing theme is nothing more than just calling `setOptions()` with new option. To recreate chart simply destroy previous one and create a new one with the same options.